# Не показываются переменные во время отладки CLion apple m1

Tags: clion

Начинаю отладку, ставлю точку остановы на строке после создания переменной, и переменная не появляется. CLion последней стабильной версии.
[image: нет переменных]

Comment: может у Вас релизная версия. Или не генерируется отладочная информация

Comment: У меня релизная версия и что это значит?

Comment: что с большой вероятностью у Вас не генерируется отладочная информация. А если нет отладочной информации, то ничего не увидите.

Comment: И как ее включить? Я пользуюсь другими jetbrains's IDEs на релизных версиях, и там все в порядке.

Comment: я не большой фанат ide от Jetbrains, но думаю, что для других языков другие правила.  Как включить? а кто его знает. В консоли я могу с помощью `-ggdb` для компилятора и потом просто gdb/lldb. Но как делать в CLion -  не знаю.